# bool? compare with bool vs GetValueOrDefault vs ?? operator

Tags: c#, nullable

With numeric it is always same *pretty*:

```
if(a < 123) { ... } // disregards if `b` is `int?` or `int`
```

But with `bool?`:

```
bool? b = ...
if(b) { ... } // compiler error: can't convert bool? to bool.
```

There are following options:

```
if(b == false) { ... } // looks ugly, comparing bool? with bool
if(b.GetValueOrDefault()) { ... } // unclear when condition is true (one must know it's `false`)
if(b.GetValueOrDefault(true)) { ... } // required few seconds to understand inversion
```

I was curios whenever nullables (at least `bool?`) deserves this syntax to be used **always**:

```
if(b ?? false) { ... } // looks best to me
```

P.S.: this may looks like opinion-based question, but I didn't find similar to clear all my doubts alone... Perhaps some of those are best used in certain scenarios and I'd like to know in which ones.

Comment: If the `bool` is null, what do you want to happen? Should the `if` block be executed, should the `else` block be executed or should neither be executed? The answer depends on that, and your examples do different things in that regard.

Comment: @Heinzi, I intentionally chosen the most *confusing* cases. Imagine you read someone else code or you have to write the one for someone. Which option you will use and why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The language designers had two choices, as far as allowing `bool?` to participate in control expressions of control statements requiring a `bool`:

- Allow it, and make an arbitrary decision when it comes to `null` treatment
- Disallow it, forcing you to make a decision each time it is relevant.

Note that the designers had much less of an issue with `if(a < 123)` statement, because "no" is a valid answer to questions "is `null` less than 123", "is `null` greater than 123", "is `null` equal to 123", and so on.

The `if (b ?? false)` and `if (b ?? true)` are very convenient constructs, which let you explain to the readers of your code and to the compiler in which way you wish to treat `null`s stored in a `bool?` variable.

Comment: Does this means you prefer `??` solution yourself? It looks the cleanest to me, pointing out what `b` can be `null` and including `null` into condition in most understandable way.

Comment: @Sinatr Absolutely, the `??` is the cleanest solution when it comes to treating `null` values inside nullables.

Comment: Interestingly, the C# designers chose option 2, whereas the VB.NET designers (unfortunately) chose option 1.

Answer (score 5):

Every time I see someone using a nullable boolean `bool?`, I ask them why.  Usually, the answer is -- "well, I'm not really sure".  It is effectively creating a three state condition which in my opinion makes the code harder to read regardless.  What does null mean, if it is always false then why bother with making it *nullable* in the first place?

But to answer your question more directly, I prefer the

```
if (b ?? false)
```

syntax over the

```
if (b.GetValueOrDefault())
```

Comment: Nullables are pretty useful (answering you question "why"). With appearance of C# 6.0 `?.` (null-conditional operator) you will see them even more.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I use them all the time -- but I try avoiding them when possible for boolean specifically since this to me is binary.  Tri-state bool is not really best practice, especially if null is always false.

Comment: Most of the time, for me anyway, bool? are for List comparaison let say this :
if(MyList?.FirstOrDefault(a => a == b)?.Value == c)
Avoid the if for the list and the if for the result clearly state that list and searched element can be null and could even be extended to the Value.

Answer (score 4):

Some years later and from personal experience I can tell that following syntax is clearly a winner:

```
if(b == false) { /* do something if false */ }
if(b == true) { /* do something if true */ }
if(b != false) { /* do something if NOT false, means true or null */ }
if(b != true) { /* do something if NOT true, means false or null */ }
```

What I thought as "ugly" turns out to be the easiest to understand.

### == vs ??

Nullables are often results of linq queries and using `??` add unnecessary layer of complexity to understand the condition.

Compare

```
if(Items?.Any(o => o.IsSelected) == true)
```

vs

```
if(Items?.Any(o => o.IsSelected) ?? false)
```

The first one is much easier to read, it's a simple check if any item is selected.

When my (probably untrained?) mind reads the latter, I have to make a mental full stop at `??`, do inversion and only then I understand when `if` block will be executed. With `??` I am likely to make a mistake when quickly looking throught the code written by someone else or even my own code given enough time has passed.